# Access denied for my user in Community mySQL version 8

Tags: mysql

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 which changed the mySQL from 5.x to 8.0.
I am in favor of using the latest software so don't want to return to 5.x.
What worked in 5.x no longer works in 8.0.

There is no trouble using the root account, but using my own user gives access errors:

```
Access denied for user 'fiji'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Access denied for user 'fiji'@'%' to database 'mytest'
```

Using Netbeans I looked at the mysql user table. Root has all the privileges Y, while my user has all of them N. I'm not sure if this is connected to the problem or not. I used this on 5.x

```
grant all on mytest.* to 'fiji'@'%' identified by 'nuke' with grant option
```

Again, I am not sure what is different in 8.0, but I noticed the identified by is slightly changed. So now I have

```
create user 'fiji'@'%' identified with caching_sha2_password by 'nuke1234'
grant all on mytest.* to 'fiji'@'%' identified with caching_sha2_password by 'nuke1234' with grant option
```

with a password expanded from 4 characters to 8. The permissions remain all N for my user and Y for root. No change in the ability to access the database, OK for root, fails for my user. I have tried everything I can think of, so I need some suggestions on what else to try.

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 0):

OK, the format of the grant command changed. This is just to maybe help someone with a similar problem. The correct command is

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mytest.* TO 'fiji'@'%'
```

It seems to be case insensitive but in my copy-paste there was upper case.

To make netbeans view data to show Y, rather than N, I would have to change mytest.(star) to (star).(star), i.e. for all databases. If I specify a particular database, then N will show, but it will be set for the given database, and I can log on with my user name.